# Check from app webpage whether related native app has been installed

Tags: javascript, html, applinks

I have an iOS and Android app and I'm building a corresponding website. I would like that the webpage, if opened using a mobile device, opens the app or its corresponding app store page (without using Facebook app links).
On the app side everything is working, including the url schema.

Does someone know how to implement this procedure, without external services, using HTML and JS?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=de&q=android%20OR%20ios%20open%20website%20in%20app

Comment: You should be able to look at the *User Agent* and see if they're coming to your site from a mobile phone. Even so, automatically redirecting to an App Store page is horrible UX (in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks for your advice @JayGould, I'll maybe not redirect the user to the appstore. I'll try out the solution you suggest.

Comment: The problem is that if I redirect the user, but he doesn't have the app, I get an error in the browser

Comment: No problem. Most sites tend to do a "We see you're using {Phone}, would you like to browse {Site} in {App}?"

Comment: Oh I thought you meant if a user literally lands on your page you immediately reroute them to your app. If you're interacting with the app via your site and need to open it, absolutely reroute them directly. In that instance the User Agent is your best bet.

Comment: I need to share the url on social networks and directly open the app if clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, this is kind of a pain to implement on your own. There is no easy way to handle everything without a ton of nasty edge cases, most notably the 'Cannot Open Page" error users will see if they don't have your app installed. **Until iOS 9,** a reasonable basic implementation was putting a JavaScript redirect like this into a dedicated redirect page on your site:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = "https://yourdomain.com";
}, 25);

// If "yourapp://" is registered, the user will see a dialog
// asking if they want to open your app. If they agree, your
// app will launch immediately and the timer won't fire.
// If not installed, you'll get an ugly "Cannot Open Page" 
// dialogue and your fallback page will open when the timer expires.

window.location = "yourapp://";
```

Unfortunately this would still show a 'Cannot Open Page' error, but until recently it was possible to get around this in a reasonably user-friendly way by using a more nuanced version of this script. Sadly, [Apple intentionally broke that with the iOS 9.2 update](https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links), so custom URL schemes are actually pretty much useless for deep linking now, unless you are **certain** the app is already installed on that device.

Apple is obviously trying to push the newer [Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) standard as much as possible. Universal Links lets you use a normal `http://` URL to a page on your website (the page could be a simple redirection to your desired fallback webpage without the custom URL trigger that causes the 'Cannot Open Page' error), which is intercepted by your phone and sent directly into your app if installed.

This is quite a lot to handle, so the best option might be a free service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) (full disclosure: I work with the team) to take care of all the technical aspects. You can find examples of apps using the Branch service [here](https://branch.io/partners/).

Comment: allow me to ask an additional question here; we have the requirement to display a user friendly banner that advertises the installation of our App, _if it's not installed already_ of course.
Do you have a direction of how to achieve that?

Comment: Hi @AdrianFöder! Take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/journeys/) — should be helpful for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Source https://encoresky.com/blog/universal-links-ios-and-app-links-android-in-react-native/

To set up universal links on IOS, needs an 'apple-app-site-association' JSON file.
To set up universal links on Android, needs an 'assetlinks.json' JSON file.

Both files need to be in the root of the web page, search the web for the proper content.